# Cascading delete with sqlite isn't working with a join table

Tags: go-gorm

If you have a table that's just a hash of a many-to-many relationship between two other tables, like :

```
type User struct{
    UserId string
    ...
}
type Roles struct{
    Level string
    ...
}
```

where UserId and Level are PrimaryKeys.
The "join table" was originally:

```
type User_Role struct{
    UserId string
    Level  string
}
```

How can you build that in gorm with cascading foreign key relataionships, et al.
I've been trying to piece it together from their docs, and different sources, but when I delete either the user or role, the join table still has the records.
Currently, this is what I've got:

```
type User_Roles struct {
    User_Id     string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null;ForeignKey:user_id;references:users.user_id,constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Level string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null;ForeignKey:level;references:roles.level,constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}
```

When I had fields in the struct for *User* and *Role* sqlite created the table with every field from both, doing it this way created the table with the right fields, but the cascading isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key checks are disabled in SQLite by default, you need to enable them:

```golang
db.Exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
```

If you specify the foreign key relations like this, they should work as you'd expect:

```golang
type User struct {
    UserId    string `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;"`
    UserRoles []User_Roles `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;references:UserId;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type User_Roles struct {
    UserId string `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;"`
    Level string `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;"`
}
```

i.e. if you delete a user, its associations will be removed.